Shopify - Create a product filter based on tags but for a specific vendor only
I have many types of products on the site. For vendor A, there are several different categories of targets, example (Gongs, Silhouettes, Spinners, etc.) with products in each category. So, while on the Vendor A collections page, we should have a custom filter called "Target Type" (with options: Gongs, Silhouettes, Spinners), and for each of those the filter should show the appropriate targets with tags that match target-gong, target-silhouette, target-spinner respectively. Now, for vendor B, C, D, etc. This filter should not show on the page, as these vendors do not sell targets at all.
